# Trouble getting file name from file path

Tags: c#, .net

How can i get filename from file path, file can be uploaded from different OSX or windows.
What am trying to achieve and what are challenges are below:

- My aim is to sanitize the file name if it has any illegal characters.
  example: OSX allows `\` and few other character that windows file system doesn't allow. the alg replaces `\` with `_`.
- Sometimes some browsers(IE) sends entire path as filename to my code. So if i upload a shared file from network in windows, IE sends the name as `\\\\servername\\folder\\filenmae.txt`

-- I can't use fileinfo or path, since filenames coming from OSX can have illegal characters such as `|`,`>`,`<` and because if the name of the filename in Mac OSX is `\\path\ex\file`, fileinfo or path gives me "file" as filename instead entire name.

-- right now, if file name has :\ in the path, i can easily extract the file name using
`filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1)`
-- but my problem is with shared files, because shared files full path pattern in windows can be a file name in OSX.

How can i get the full name?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You have no way of knowing whether `\\a\b\c.txt` is a full path from Windows or an unusual filename from *nix.

Comment: What are the rules applied to a filename in OSX?

Comment: google please!, i know :-)

Comment: @DineshB Sure I was kidding about OSX. :) This seems to be a hard one. Though you could try a little experiment. If you share files between Windows and OSX, do the same problems occur (e.g. if you have a weird filename on your MAC, can you access it via Windows)?

Comment: good question!, it may give you an error if you try to copy

Comment: @SLaks It can be done!, thanks for the response.

Comment: @DineshB: No; it cannot be done.  There is no difference between the string `\\a\b\c.txt` as a full path on Windows and the string `\\a\b\c.txt` as a filename on Mac.

Comment: @SLaks Actual problem was with IE.Example if you trying to upload a file from \\<server>\b\c.txt,In IE the file name will be sent as \\<server>\b\c.txt, in others it is sent as c.txt.Using FileInfo, if you try to get the directory name (IE file name) it gives you \\<server>\b. When you query same info for a path coming from chrome or any browser or any OS as far as i know ,it gives you c:\\windows\\system32 as its directory.

Comment: continue... Look at my solution below. Its looks whether the filename starts with its directory name.In case below its not true .  If i upload \\a\b\c.txt from mac osx -> dir  is c:\\windows\\system32\\a\\b

Comment: @DineshB: File paths **are** strings.  Only IE sends the full path; other browsers just send the filename.  `FileInfo` is resolving the filename relative to the current directory, which is system32.  I'm still right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses, special thanks to @Dour High Arch . Figured out the solution finally. Using fileInfo class, can be done with Path as well but not yet tested.

```
try
{
  FileInfo fileInformation = new FileInfo(tempFileName);
  String directory = fileInformation.DirectoryName;
  if (tempFileName.StartsWith(directory))
  {
    filename = fileInformation.Name;
  }
}
catch (Exception arugmentException)
{
   if (!((arugmentException is ArgumentException) || 
     (arugmentException is NotSupportedException))) throw;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the static methods of [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

[`Path.GetFileName(string);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and [`Path.GetDirectoryName(string);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: doesn't work with OSX, example filename of file in osx is test<>/\.txt, throws an exception, secondly what if the filename is a path, which is true in OSX.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out; this cannot work. You cannot create filenames that work across all OSes, or even filenames that work across all filesystems in a single OS. I ran into this problem trying to copy NTFS files to an ISO 9660 drive from Windows.

Do not attempt to “sanitize” filenames; the rules are too unreliable, and conflict across filesystems. Use your OS’s API to construct files, like `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName` or `System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog`. If you are trying to construct filenames programmatically, pass a name you believe will work across all client filesystems, like "MyFile" plus an incrementing sequence number, or a hexadecimal GUID, to the API and be prepared for filesystem exceptions when they don’t work.

If you are copying files across filesystems, it is a good idea to store the original filename to show to users, and to use it as the default for File Save dialogs and the like but, again, don’t write your programs to rely on them.

Comment: i understand but, what if someone uploads a file from OS X with filename text<>/\.txt, and the other person tries to download on windows. (ignore how i would store it on sever)

Comment: Show the person the name "text<>/\.txt" in the UI. If you try to save that on Windows it will throw, and you will have to make the user try again or create your own name. But that can happen with any filename from a user; it is irrelevant whether the name came from a different filesystem.

Comment: good idea, but my task is to rename such files. As of now a temp solution - try { filename = path.getFileName(fileName) } catch(Exception e) { if(!(e is ArgumentException)) throw;} filename=renameFileName(fileName);

Comment: Do not pass `fileName` to `renameFileName`; if `fileName` throws you cannot reliably determine why. Instead, `renameFileName` should use a filesystem-dependent rule to create a new name.

Comment: exception will be thrown only when filename is has invalid characters, if it throws an exception it is evident that file is from OS X. and renamingFileName alg renames filename to OS independent. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @DineshB, be aware filenames composed only of valid characters (e.g. '....') can throw. Valid filenames (e.g. 'PRN') can throw.